# How to use _controller suffix on controller name using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, routes

I want to use _controller suffix on controller name and don't show this suffix in url.

Controller name that i have created -

```
admin_controller
```

so in my url i access it like this **(here controller name is admin_controller)**

```
http://localhost/DemoTest/index.php?c=admin_controller&m=dashboard&d=admin
```

But I want it like this **(here controller name is admin)**

```
http://localhost/DemoTest/index.php?c=admin&m=dashboard&d=admin
```

Comment: Have you tried routing using `$route` ?

Comment: I want to use without $route because i use $route then i have to define all controller's rule